# Crystal Report Not display all the report pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have multiple pages in my crystal report but it display `1,2 and 258` page fine but page 3 to 257 page not display on my report page

i code like this

```
private void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["reportDocument"] != null)
    {        
        reportDocument = (ReportDocument)Session["reportDocument"];
        Session["reportDocument"] = null;
        rptClients.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        Session["reportDocument"] = reportDocument;
    }
}
```

and i fill the session value in blow code

```
protected void FillClientsReport()
{
    int _group = Convert.ToInt32(rbtnlClients.SelectedValue);
    int CompanyId = int.Parse(ddlCompany.SelectedValue);

    rptClients.ReportSource = null;

    reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/ClientList.rpt"));

    DataSet ds = _clientService.GetClientsReport(_group, CompanyId);
    reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon
    (myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName, myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName);
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@GroupBy", _group);
    reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@CompanyID", CompanyId);
    reportDocument.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
    rptClients.Visible = true;
    //ViewState["reportDocument"] = reportDocument;
    Session["reportDocument"] = reportDocument;
    rptClients.ReportSource = reportDocument;
    rptClients.DataBind();
    rptClients.RefreshReport();
}
```

Comment: Is it blank pages in report?

Comment: yes it display blank report

Comment: In which event  you call FillClientsReport() method?

Comment: i call this on button click for display report

Comment: `protected void bttnShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["reportDocument"] = null;
        FillClientsReport();
    }`

Comment: Comment this two lines 
 rptClients.DataBind();
        rptClients.RefreshReport();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24033/discussion-between-saroop-trivedi-and-a-goutam)